# Makefiles: Get .cpp from one directory and put the compiled .o in another directory

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a cross-platform 2D engine for mobile devices (Windows Mobile 6 and Android). My Windows version is pretty much ready, but I still need to make sure the same functionality is available on Android.

What I want is one `Makefile` in the root of the project and several `Makefile`'s for the project itself and the test applications.

```
Makefile
---Engine
------Makefile
------src
------bin
------intermediate
---Tests
------TestOne
---------Makefile
---------src
---------bin
---------intermediate
------TestTwo
---------Makefile
---------src
---------bin
---------intermediate
```

I'm basing my attempts on the following `Makefile`:

```
 include ../makeinclude

 PROGS = test1
 SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)

 # first compile main.o and start.o, then compile the rest
 OBJECTS = main.o start.o $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

 all: $(PROGS)

 clean:
    rm -f *.o src

 test1: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) --entry=_start --dynamic-linker system/bin/linker -nostdlib -rpath system/lib -rpath $(LIBS) -L $(LIBS) -lm -lc -lui -lGLESv1_CM $^ -o ../$@ 
    acpy ../$(PROGS)
 .cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(GLES_INCLUDES) -c $*.cpp $(CLIBS)
```

However, I'm not very good with these things. What I want is for it to take the .cpp's that are in the `src` folder, compile them to .o and put them in the `intermediate` folder and, finally, compile the .o's to the compiled exe and put it in the `bin` folder.

I've managed to get clean to work like this:

```
cd intermediate && rm -f *.o
```

However, I can't get it to retrieve the .cpp's, compile them and put them in the `intermediate` folder.

I've looked at several other `Makefiles`, but none do the things I want to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, specify "make" tag instead of "makefile".  More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Comment: Well, I *am* a noob concerning these things. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but the simplest is to run in TestOne, making Intermediate/foo.o out of Src/foo.cpp and test1 out of Intermediate/foo.o, like this:

```
# This makefile resides in TestOne, and should be run from there.

include makeinclude # Adjust the path to makeinclude, if need be.

PROG = bin/test1 
SOURCES = $(wildcard Src/*.cpp) 

# Since main.cpp and start.cpp should be in Src/ with the rest of
# the source code, there's no need to single them out
OBJECTS = $(patsubst Src/%.cpp,Intermediate/%.o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(PROG)

clean: 
    rm -f Intermediate/*.o bin/*

$(PROG): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LD) $(BLAH_BLAH_BLAH) $^ -o ../$@  

$(OBJECTS): Intermediate/%.o : Src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(GLES_INCLUDES) -c $< $(CLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you! :D

This was exactly what I needed. I love makefile's (much more than Visual Studio's vcproj), but they can be so difficult to set up. :(

Comment: I like them too, but they have some serious shortcomings and a long learning curve... and since I didn't actually test this, there's a bug. Hang on a sec...